# Dúvida sobre parte teórica de web services

Tags: web-service

Olá, pessoal. Estou estudando a parte de web services e estou um pouco confuso com a parte teórica. Estava lendo o artigo deste site

http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-as-tecnologias-web-services-soa-soap-wsdl-e-uddi-parte1/2873

E fiquei confuso com a definição de "web service intermediário".
Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de Android simples, como se fosse um exercício, que realiza o cadastro e login de usuários.

Neste programa, criei o web service pelo Eclipse e um aplicativo Android para consumir o web service. Neste caso, o meu web service e aplicativo Android simplesmente são provedor e solicitante de serviço, respectivamente?

Alguém saberia de algum exemplo que possua um web service intermediário?

E qual seria o propósito de existir um webservice intermediário? porque, pensando de modo simples, a mensagem não poderia ir direto ao destino em vez de passar por outro web service?

E no caso do meu projeto que só tem um web service e um aplicativo Android, ele o aplicativo Android pode ser considerado um "remetente inicial"? No caso, o aplicativo Android é considerado um web service também?

Espero por respostas e muito obrigado a todos que postarem alguma resposta.

Answer (score 4):

> Neste programa, criei o web service pelo Eclipse e um aplicativo
>   Android para consumir o web service. Neste caso, o meu web service e
>   aplicativo Android simplesmente são provedor e solicitante de serviço,
>   respectivamente?

Se entendi a estrutura, sim. Não há intermediário aqui.

> Alguém saberia de algum exemplo que possua um web service
>   intermediário?

Um intermediário seria um serviço terceiro (terceirizado) conhecido em inglês como "third party".

**Vamos a um exemplo no mundo real, para melhor entendimento**

Um Web Service para envio de SMS. Quando usa um serviço terceiro de envio de SMS, está a usar um intermediário. Pois o seu aplicativo solicita que um terceiro envie a mensagem para o destino final. Não há uma comunicação direta entre origem e destino.

Com intermediário

```
[origem] <-> [webservice terceiro] <-> [destino]
```

Sem intermediário

```
[origem] <-> [destino]
```

Outro exemplo de intermediário são gateways de pagamento.
Os gateways fazem o intermédio entre o solicitante da requisição e o destino final que são as instituições financeiras.

Comment: Eu que sou totalmente fora desta área de conhecimento consegui entender tudo. Explicação simples e objetiva.